# image upload using parse API

Tags: android

I am having trouble trying to upload the image on server using Parse API. I can read from the server and update data on any column except uploading image.

I have picked the image from the device and displayed in imageView..

```
// Move to first row
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

// Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
Picasso.with(this).load(selectedImage).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);

//resizing the image part 2
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//to Compress the image
//Quality Accepts 0 - 100
//0 = MAX Compression (Least Quality which is suitable for Small images)
//100 = Least Compression (MAX Quality which is suitable for Big images)
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, baos);

//uploading the image to server
byte[] imageInByte = imgDecodableString.getBytes();
final ParseFile bitmapFile = new ParseFile(imageInByte);
bitmapFile.saveInBackground();

//current user is already logged in.
ParseObject userDisplayImage = new ParseObject("UserDisplayImage");
userDisplayImage.put("photo", bitmapFile);
userDisplayImage.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: You should try getting response from the server in that `saveInBackground()` using `saveInBackground(new SaveCallback {...})`. Also, make sure to check the parse exception using : `if (e != null) e.printStacktrace();`

Comment: I did and still get the same error - toast "null photo file". I think from the server.

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
final ParseFile bitmapFile = new ParseFile(imageInByte);
bitmapFile.saveInBackground();
```

the `bitmapFile` is uploaded in a background thread, hence by the time you reach to the next statement :

```
ParseObject userDisplayImage = new ParseObject("UserDisplayImage");
userDisplayImage.put("photo", bitmapFile);
userDisplayImage.saveInBackground (...);
```

The `bitmapFile` is not completely uploaded and hence it `userDisaplyImage` is not able to make a pointer towards it.

You can try the following to fix it :

```
final ParseFile bitmapFile = new ParseFile(imageInByte);
bitmapFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
        if(e==null){
             Log.i("hello","  photo saved ");
             ParseObject userDisplayImage = new ParseObject("UserDisplayImage");
             userDisplayImage.put("photo", bitmapFile);
             userDisplayImage.saveInBackground ();
        } else {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Log.i("Error", e + "photo not saved");
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: I did the same thing but received same message .. toast "null photo file". I think from the server.

Comment: It is coming from Toast. It was null file and + "photo file". I removes the toast. Still no photo uploaded.

Comment: So you mean you have no statement in your code that says something like `Toast.makeText(context, "null photo file", Toast.LONG)` ? If not, I guess the judgement day is near, and in that case, I wont be able to help.

Comment: There was a Toast and I removed the toast but no file uploaded to the server.

Comment: Its actually very simple to do this. I am sure you are doing something wrong. But in anycase, this is all I can do ..

Comment: Can somebody else help me?